# Quartz: Can schedule be shutdown automatically after job execution?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz

As default, quartz schedule is not shutdown after job execution. Can schedule be shutdown automatically after job execution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Scheduler has only start method. However, you can control the repeat count, i.e how many times the scheduler should trigger.

Check the below snippet.

```
trigger = newTrigger()
.withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
.startAt(myTimeToStartFiring)  // if a start time is not given (if this line were omitted), "now" is implied
.withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
    .withIntervalInSeconds(10)
    .withRepeatCount(10)) // note that 10 repeats will give a total of 11 firings
.forJob(myJob) // identify job with handle to its JobDetail itself                   
.build();
```